# Best way to open a third party url in popup/webview and track the same url using react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-router

Folks, Need some ideas and thoughts around Reactjs. Agenda is to launch an url in popup or an iframe and track the url while moving forward in popped out window. I have implemented [React Poput](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-popout) but unable to track the window URL.

The url in popup is supposed to be of third party application.

Code:

```
<Popout url='/hiddenFormSubmit' ref={popoutRef => this.popoutRef = popoutRef} containerId='hiddenContainer' options={{height:'650px'}} title='Window title' onClosing={this.popoutClosed}>
</Popout>
```

Functions:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isPoppedOut: false
    };

 popout() {
    console.log(" Popout URL::");
    this.setState({isPoppedOut: true });
  }


 popoutClosed() {
   this.setState({isPoppedOut: false});
  }
```

My Hidden Form Component opening in popout

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
export default class Perfios extends Component {
  static propTypes = {}
  static defaultProps = {}
  state = {}
constructor(props){
  super(props);

}
componentDidMount(){
  this.myform.submit();
}

  render() {
    const { className, ...props } = this.props;
    return(
    <form ref={myform => this.myform = myform} method="POST" action="https://xyz.in/abc/url-third-party">
         <input ref="inputField" name="id" type="hidden" value="11" />
         <input name="adminId" type="hidden" value="123" />
         <input name="surname" type="hidden" value="xyz" />
         <button className="hidden" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
         </form>
       );
   }
}
```

In above code, form is getting submitted on component mount & redirecting to third party url.

Find the [Demo](http://jake.ginnivan.net/react-popout/). How to track the popped window's url in parent container? Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Im not sure understood the question. Just saying does History API of html5 of any use?